# Unable to open .sln in Core 1.0 version

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-1.0

Can we open VS 2013 solution file in Core 1.0. I downloaded a zip from github in my mac and trying to open the .sln in Core 1.0 version but its not opening the whole project.

Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Please note, i'm just trying Core 1.0 for the first time. if this question appears to be lame, please pardon me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does not use solution files at all.  To edit that project you would need to open the folder which contains the solution files.  However, a project which was written in VS2013 won't be targeting the .NET Core runtime anyway, so you wouldn't be able to run it on a Mac or Linux machine using the .NET CLI.